# How do you make the console print false when the words are out of order? Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, if-statement, include, var

The current code makes console prints true when `message == 'john hi'`, but I need it to print false when the words are out of order.

Elements in array1 should come first, elements in array2 should come second and I should be able to add more arrays after array2 if I wanted to.

Examples of what I NEED the code to do:

When `message == 'hi john'` //prints true

When `message == 'and hey evan'` //prints true

When `message == 'john hi'` //prints false because array2 came first

```
var array1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
var array2 = ['john', 'evan', 'matthew']
var message = ''

if (array1.some(element => message.includes(element)) && array2.some(element => message.includes(element))) {
  console.log(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linear algorithm that makes sure that:

1. A word from array 1 is never behind a word from array 2
2. A word from array 2 is never 'hit' before an array 1 word

```
function checkWordOrder(array1, array2, str) {
    const words = str.split(' ');
    const wordsLength = words.length;
    const array1Length = array1.length;
    const arrayConcat = array1.concat(array2);
    let hitArray1 = false;
    let hitArray2 = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < wordsLength; ++i) {
        const index = arrayConcat.indexOf(words[i]);

        if (index != -1) { // Word is found in either array
            if (index < array1Length) {
                if (hitArray2) return false;
                hitArray1 = true;
            } else if (index >= array1Length) {
                if (!hitArray1) return false;
                hitArray2 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

let array1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey'];
let array2 = ['john', 'evan', 'matthew'];

console.log(checkWordOrder(array1, array2, 'hi john'));         // true
console.log(checkWordOrder(array1, array2, 'and hey evan'));    // true
console.log(checkWordOrder(array1, array2, 'john hi'));         // false
console.log(checkWordOrder(array1, array2, 'hi john john hi')); // false
console.log(checkWordOrder(array1, array2, 'random'));          // true
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach, we look for the last occurrence of words from each array. So this might be [5,0]. These should be in order, and if they're not we reject.

```
var array1 = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey'];
var array2 = ['john', 'evan', 'matthew'];
var arrayOfArrays = [array1, array2];

function isInOrder(arr)
{  
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++ ) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])  return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function wordsAreInOrder(message) {
    var maxIndexes = arrayOfArrays.map((a) => {
          return Math.max.apply(null, a.map((value) => { return message.indexOf(value) }));
    });

    console.log('The latest occurrence of words from each array: ', maxIndexes);

    return isInOrder(maxIndexes);
}

console.log('Is in order: ' + wordsAreInOrder('hi john'));
console.log('Is in order: ' + wordsAreInOrder('and hey evan'));
console.log('Is in order: ' + wordsAreInOrder('john hi'));
```